# Can't import AlertifyJS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, import, alertifyjs

When importing [AlertifyJS](https://alertifyjs.com/), I am able to successfully use script tags in the HTML like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.13.1/alertify.min.js"></script>
```

But if I move the import into JS using `import * as alertify from './AlertifyJS';` I can't get my project to recognise the library. But everything I have read says this should work, am I doing something wrong?

I have also tried other examples like;

`import alertifyjs from 'alertifyjs';`

`import * as alertify from 'alertify.js';`

`var alertify = require('alertifyjs');`

Answer (score 1):

You can't export JS from HTML. You can import it however, using the type="module" attribute on the  tag:

```
    <script type="module">
        import alertifyjs from 'alertifyjs';

        alertifyjs.myAlert("Browser dialogs made easy!");
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to import the lib inside the JS file though, not the HTML file.

Comment: @w4dd325 what framework are you using?

Comment: .NET VisualStudio 2019

Comment: It would appear (after having a similar issue with 'require') that I need to read up on client-side vs server-side JS. Having come back to this your answer makes more sense, I still clearly have a lot to learn but I understand what you said now!